# Specific thread order in C using GCC and OMP

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, gcc, openmp

I need to make 4 teams with 4 threads each one with contiguous processors.

The result I'm expecting is, for example:

```
Team 0 Thread 0 Processor: 0
Team 0 Thread 1 Processor: 1
Team 0 Thread 2 Processor: 2
Team 0 Thread 3 Processor: 3
Team 1 Thread 0 Processor: 4
Team 1 Thread 1 Processor: 5
Team 1 Thread 2 Processor: 6
Team 1 Thread 3 Processor: 7
Team 2 Thread 0 Processor: 8
Team 2 Thread 1 Processor: 9
Team 2 Thread 2 Processor: 10
Team 2 Thread 3 Processor: 11
Team 3 Thread 0 Processor: 12
Team 3 Thread 1 Processor: 13
Team 3 Thread 2 Processor: 14
Team 3 Thread 3 Processor: 15
```

I can handle Processor Affinity in GCC using the GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY variable.

I'm using:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
```

twice in order to get 2 fork levels.

At the moment I'm having this order in GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY:

```
0 4 8 12 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15
```

So the first fork, the "fathers fork", gets:

```
Team 0 Thread 0 Processor: 0
Team 1 Thread 0 Processor: 4
Team 2 Thread 0 Processor: 8
Team 3 Thread 0 Processor: 12
```

The problem I'm having is that the second group of forks make without any order so, for example I could have this situation (I'm using #pragma omp atomic so only one 'father' can ask for more processors at any time):

```
Team 0 Thread 0 Processor: 0
Team 0 Thread 1 Processor: 5
Team 0 Thread 2 Processor: 6
Team 0 Thread 3 Processor: 7
Team 1 Thread 0 Processor: 4
Team 1 Thread 1 Processor: 13
Team 1 Thread 2 Processor: 14
Team 1 Thread 3 Processor: 15
Team 2 Thread 0 Processor: 8
Team 2 Thread 1 Processor: 1
Team 2 Thread 2 Processor: 2
Team 2 Thread 3 Processor: 3
Team 3 Thread 0 Processor: 12
Team 3 Thread 1 Processor: 9
Team 3 Thread 2 Processor: 10
Team 3 Thread 3 Processor: 11
```

The question is: Is there any way to make this second petition in order?

I think I would have to make some sinchronization method with locks or something...

Thanks in advance!

- Javier

Comment: Why, why, why, why?  Threads are supposed to work asynchronously.  This question comes up more often than 'floating point compares do not work'.

Comment: @Martin: He's not talking about synchronizing anything, he's talking about assignment of thread IDs to processor IDs (which might be important on a NUMA system)

Comment: @MartinJames: What is wrong with assigning threads to specific processor cores? Ensuring that threads which share data operate on the same processor to minimize false sharing impacts can be vitally important for performance on ccNUMA systems afterall.

Comment: Well Martin that's why (why why)... I have a NUMA system and, in addition, processors share cache in groups! I think I figure out how to solve it, let me try a few things and I'll post if I'm right... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could make this works, this is my code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int padre, hijo;

    int contador = 0;
    omp_set_nested(1);
    int suma;
    #pragma omp parallel private(padre) shared(contador) num_threads(4)
    {
        padre = omp_get_thread_num();

        {

            while(contador != padre){
                // Don't know what to put here
            };

            #pragma omp parallel private(hijo) shared(padre, contador) num_threads(4)
            {
                hijo = omp_get_thread_num();
                printf("\nFather: %d Son: %d Processor: %d\n", padre, hijo, sched_getcpu());
                #pragma omp master
                {
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Padre is Father, Hijo is Son and Contador is Counter in Spanish :P

The problem I'm facing now is that if I compile my code with -O3 optimizations, the while loop 'dissapear' unless I put, for example, a printf line inside the loop. I think I should ask it in another question!

Thanks to you all!

- Javier