# Don't optimize an specific loop using -O3 flag in GCC

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gcc, openmp

In my code I use a simple int variable (named counter) to synchronize 4 threads.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
int counter = 0;
#pragma omp parallel shared(counter) num_threads(4) 
{
    while(counter != thread_id){
        // What should I put here?
    }
    // Actions needed to be performed 'in order'
    counter++;
    // The rest of the code
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that if I use -O3 optimization flag, the while loop 'dissapear' in the compiled code... If for example I put a printf line inside the loop, the while takes place and everything works OK...

What should I put inside my while loop so -O3 doesn't affect it's behaviour?

--- Edit ---

Sorry for the lack of context... I need to create teams of threads that work on specific proccessors since I'm working with a NUMA system so I need the "team creation" part make in order so I can use processor affinity... Please, see this question related: 
[Specific thread order in C using GCC and OMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167265/specific-thread-order-in-c-using-gcc-and-omp)

Comment: Are you trying to synchronize/join your threads?  OpenMP already has constructs to do that.  Don't try to roll your own; that completely defeats the point!

Comment: If you're trying to sync threads this way, **I'll downvote all answers that tell you how to do it**.

Comment: As a general rule, if a loop appears to do nothing of any consequence, you should not be surprised if it is simply dropped by the optimizer.

Comment: Right, but I am doing something in the loop... It's an active wait... Is there a way to tell the compiler that I need that loop without including some dummy functions inside?

Comment: I have upvoted the Oli/Luchian comments.  Why? 'Cos they're right.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this is a BAD way to synchronise threads. Since I don't want my answer downvoted, I'll explain that you should use some other form of synchronization. Typically, a semphore is used to count things, so that would PROBABLY be the right thing here, but since we don't have all your code, there isn't a particularly good way to tell.